# SlidingPaneLayout.getState(); not found

Tags: java, android

I want use SlidingPaneLayout.getState(); but didn't found.
Is it removed and when?

```
public void showAudioPlayer() {
        mActivityHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActionBar.collapseActionView();
                int state = mSlidingPane.getState();
                mSlidingPane.getClass();
                if (state == 0) {
                    mSlidingPane.openPane();
                }
                mAudioPlayerFilling.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SlidingPaneLayout` has no static or instance method called `getState()`. This can be verified by viewing the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout).

You may wish to instead use its instance method `isOpen()` or implement a `SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener` as appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: In `SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener`, I want to use
       `@Override
        public void onPanelOpenedEntirely() {
            
        }`   with `com.android.widget.SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener`

Comment: also I want to know that was there a static method called `getState()` in past versions ?